# Is it possible to reach a monochromatic configuration only using 2x2 and 5x5 flips?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

The following problem has been troubling me for quite a while now:

"The cells of a $10\times 10$ grid are either coloured blue or green. In a move you are allowed to select any $2\times 2$ or $5\times 5$ grid and reverse the colour of each cell in that "sub-grid". Is it possible to make all cells blue given any starting configuration?"

My intuition says tells me that this is possible. I first tried to find a sequence of moves to switch the colour of one cell and thus use this as many times as needed but this was easier said than done and I could not find this algorithm. I could however prove that this was impossible only using $2\times 2$ flips using the sum of the cells modulo $2$ being an invariant (assigning 1 to green and 0 to blue). Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: It's just a system of $9\times 9+6\times 6$ linear equations over $\mathbb{F}_2$. Anything like Gaussian elimination will do.

Comment: @Alexey Burdin I've seen people using stuff like that to solve problems like these but never understood them, could you please elaborate. I am not familiar with that kind of stuff.

Comment: What contest is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of the cell values as $0$ or $1$, and using mod-2 arithmetic, an operation like "change, in a 2x2 square, all greens to blue and blues to green" becomes "add $1$ to each item in the $2 \times 2$ square."

For $i, j = 1, \ldots 9$, let's call $T(i,j)$ the $10 \times 10$ matrix that's all zeroes except for locations $(i,j), (i+1,j), (i, j+1), (i+1,j+1)$, i.e., all locations except for a $2 \times 2$ block whose upper left corner is at location $(i, j)$. Similarly, let $F(i, j)$ be the $10 \times 10$ matrix that's all zeroes except for having $1$s in an $5 \times 5$ block whose upper left corner is at $(i, j)$. Here $i, j = 1, \ldots, 6$), because you can't fit a $5 \times 5$ matrix of $1$s starting anywhere after the 6th row or columns.

Now the problem becomes (everything is 10 x 10 from now on):

Given a matrix $M$, is there a collection of $T$ and $F$ matrices such that
$$
M + T_1 + T_2 + \ldots + T_k + F_1 + 
\ldots + F_p = 0?
$$

which is equivalent, $\bmod 2$, to
$$
M = T_1 + T_2 + \ldots + T_k + F_1 + 
\ldots + F_p = 0.
$$

In other words, do the matrices $T(i,j)$ and $F(i, j)$ span $M_10(\Bbb F_2)$?

By writing out each $10 \times 10$ matrix as a column vector (just stack the columns on top of each other!), you get $81$ column vectors $t_{ij}$ for the $T$ matrices, and another $36$ vectors $f_{ij}$ for the $F$ matrices. The question is whether these $117$ matrices actually span. Fortunately, that's easy to answer: you take the $100 \times 117$ mod-2 matrix, and row reduce it to see whether it has at least $100$ independent columns. (I said it was easy; I didn't say it'd be fast!)

My guess, from a little fiddling, is that they do not span. I could write some matlab code to check, but...it's time to move on.

====

OK, I wrote the code, in analogy with the other answer mentioned in the comments, and found that each of the $T$ and $F$ matrices has the property that $M \cdot X = 0 \bmod 2$, where $X$ is this matrix

```
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 1     1     0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1
```

To put it differently: every $2 \times 2$ and $5 \times 5$ submatrix of $X$ sums to $0 \bmod 2$. So in summing up $T$ and $F$ matrices, you will never get the matrix $E$ with a $1$ in the lower left corner and zeroes everywhere else, because the dot-product of $E$ with $X$ is $1$ rather than $0$.

Here's how I found that matrix (with amazingly ugly matlab code)

```
function grid_puzzle2()

twos =   zeros(10, 10, 9, 9); % room for all 81 10x10 mats with 2x2 blocks of ones. 
fives =  zeros(10, 10, 6, 6);
for i = 1:9
    for j = 1:9
        twos(i:i+1,j:j+1, i, j) = 1; % fill in the blocks
    end
end
% restructure the 4-index matrix to a 2-index one, where each column
% is the result of reading out the columns of one 10x10 matrix. 
% Yeah, putting the indices in the right order for this takes practice. 
t2 = reshape(twos, [100, 81]);
for i = 1:6
    for j = 1:6
        fives(i:i+4,j:j+4, i, j) = 1;
    end
end
t5 = reshape(fives, [100, 36]);
T = [t2, t5]; % a 100 x 117 matrix
S = rref(T'); % the row-reduced version of the transpose of $T$
U = ones(117, 1); % a list of 117 "1"s
x = S\U ; % "best possible" solution of Sx = U
```

These computations are all done over the reals, so the vector $x$ ends up with entries that are all (by chance) multiples of $0.25$. So I computed

```
t = round(4*x); 
s = mod(t, 2)
```

and got the matrix that I pasted in above.

Now WHY is solving $Sx = u$ the right thing to do? I wanted a matrix whose dot product with each $2 \times 2$ and $5 \times 5$ matrix was the same. If I'd picked $u = 0$, which is the obvious choice, the natural solution would be $x = 0$, which would be of no use. So picking $u$ to be all $2$s is a better choice. I used all $1$s because it was easier to express in Matlab, and then fiddled a little at the end.

Comment: BTW, @JohnTom, you might find the solution to an analogous problem here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3779625/6-times-6-grid-problem/3780005#3780005) useful as part of a general strategy for problems like these.

Comment: $92$ are linearly independent, python source [here](https://tio.run/##fU/basQgEH3PVwh90caWZkuhBPyS4ILbuK02Ga0xYL4@zcQ0WVqoDw5n9Nz8FD8cPL/6MM@m9y5EYqIO0bluKPTXIJpBR1qQ5dBUmpJOpWX31RMjVxeI4ZYYOBiPPrh2fIs0KHjXFBgP2msVxYmtEvlGJiCvOfEXua8Sn/4Tq6qHP3qyuPPdOIhO9ZdWoUI9LBV0SzF1YmccE2PFGhbVs1angS7lGKtXmSQa2huglnHIwnvMXFDD2OugokZWY2rJzfHPXIndQa6zrMBFkup974OBSG9Yl6DV54oW58RBYICU31cTyXGAFHnwvNzy3gCMaY9qpqz4r3pbIuRYSRS0aEkzZAKNb4L@@Ft53lzm@Rs), so now it's to construct unsolvable matrix?

Comment: Done. Matlab is really good at this kind of thing. :)

Comment: It would be much faster to answer if we have had $7\times 7$ instead of $5\times 5$.

Comment: @Aqua: indeed, because $81 + 16 = 97 < 100$.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that every $5\times 5$ submatrix of $X$ contains exactly $8$ 1s and every $2\times 2$ submatrix contains $0$ or $2$ 1s, so the sum of elements of the original matrix in places of $1$s in $X$ modulo $2$ is like an "invariant". It solves the problem. However, I don't see how exactly did you construct $X$ from the equations. Maybe you could share the script? Not sure I read matlab though) Thanks @JohnHughes

Comment: Shared in the answer.

Comment: BTW, the nullspace of the matrix $S$ in the program is something like 8-dimensional, so there may be some much more "obvious" choice for $X$....but I've run out of time to investigate this.